# How to write cv.Set(cv.fromarray) from Python 2 to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, porting

I just installed `python 3`, but many `python 2` programs have errors in `python 3`.

How to write

```
cv.Set(cv.fromarray(t),cv.Scalar(0.0,0,0,0),cv.fromarray(band))
```

in `python 3`?